# loading combined data in R

Tags: r

I have got several Excel files (see link: we.tl/t-qJl3kVcY0j) that I combine together.
Each Excel file have columns from `A` to `AF` as below:

`t-ph`
`Load`
`HR`
`BF`
`V'E`
`V'O2`
`V'CO2`
`d  O2/dW`
`RER`
`EqO2`
`EqCO2`
`PETCO2`
`VES (ml)`
`VESi (ml/m²)`
`FC (bpm)`
`QC (l/min)`
`IC (l/min/m²)`
`PAS (mmHg)`
`PAD (mmHg)`
`PAM (mmHg)`
`ICT`
`TEV (ms)`
`RPD (%)`
`WCI (kg.m/m²)`
`RVSi (dyn.s/cm5.m²)`
`RVS (dyn.s/cm5)`
`VTD est (ml)`
`FE est (%)`
`O2Hb`
`HHb`
`tHb`
`HbDiff`

My previous code was working, but since I have added columns AC (`HHb`) to AF (`HbDiff`), I can't load them anymore. I have tried to match the number of columns, the title, but still not. I can't produce a reproducible example since I can't load my data.

Here is the code I used:

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, readxl, ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

library(afex) ##statistic package

# load data and format
load_files <- function(files){
  temp <- read_excel(files) %>% 
    select(-(c(8:11, 14:15, 18:23))) %>%
    mutate(id = pull(.[4,1])) %>% ##ID
    mutate(body_mass = pull(.[7,3])) %>% ##body mass
    mutate(training = pull(.[4,2])) %>% ##training group
    set_names(c("time", "power", "hr", "fr", "VE", "absVO2", "VCO2", "PETCO2", "VES", "QC", "IC", "WCI", "RVSi", "RVS", "VTD", "FE", "O2Hb", "HHb", "tHb", "HbDiff", "id", "body_mass", "training")) %>% 
    slice(86:which(grepl("ration", VE))-1) %>% ##until recovery period
    mutate_at(vars(1:16), as.numeric) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(18), as.numeric) %>% 
    mutate(time = format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + time), "%H:%M", tz="UTC"),
           absVO2 = absVO2/1000, 
           VCO2 = VCO2/1000)
}

# apply function to all files
df <- map_df(file_list, load_files)


# remove those with who have less than four similar power
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(len_seq = rep(rle(power)$lengths, rle(power)$lengths)) %>% 
  filter(len_seq == 4) %>% 
  mutate(seq_id = rep(1:(n()/4), each = 4)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  select(-seq_id)%>% 
  select(-(20))


# group data
df_sum <- df %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(id, power, training) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(percent_absVO2 = absVO2/max(absVO2)*100,
         percent_power = power/max(power)*100,
         percent_QC = QC/max(QC)*100,
         percent_SV = VES/max(VES)*100,
         percent_VCO2 = VCO2/max(VCO2)*100,
         percent_VE = VE/max(VE)*100) %>%
  mutate(VE_VO2 = VE/absVO2,
         VE_VCO2 = VE/VCO2) %>%
  mutate(RER = VCO2/absVO2, VT = VE/fr) %>%
  mutate(relVO2 = absVO2/body_mass*1000,
         percent_relVO2 = relVO2/max(relVO2)*100) %>%
  mutate(BF = VE/VT) %>%
  mutate(mech_perf = (power/(((0.003*power+0.1208)*1000*body_mass)/60))*100) %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(grepl(".*-PRD-C", id), "CAD", "Healthy")) %>%
  mutate(temps = ifelse(grepl(".*-PRD-C1", id), "1", ifelse(grepl(".*-PRD-S1", id), "1", "2")))
```

Then the outcome I get:

```
Error in `set_names()`:
! The size of `nm` (23) must be compatible with the size of `x` (20).
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Thank you very much for your precious help.

Comment: Your code `set_names(c("time", "power", "hr", "fr", "VE", "absVO2", "VCO2", "PETCO2", "VES", "QC", "IC", "WCI", "RVSi", "RVS", "VTD", "FE", "id", "body_mass", "training"))` assumes that all of those columns will be present.  Instead, modify it to `rename_with` using a key/value pair so that it will only match the columns present to modify

Comment: Sorry, I very new on this. Do you mean change for that: `rename_with(c("time", "power", "hr", "fr", "VE", "absVO2", "VCO2", "PETCO2", "VES", "QC", "IC", "WCI", "RVSi", "RVS", "VTD", "FE", "id", "body_mass", "training"))` ? I wanted to remove some columns in my code, and add others such as `id`, `body_mass`, and `training`, calculated just previously in the code.

Comment: Do you have a vector of original columns names that you want to change?  If `v1` is the original column names, i.e. `v1 <- c("col1", "col2", "french")`, then within the code `.. %>% rename_with(~ c("time", "power", "fr"), any_of(v1)) %>%...  `any_of` checks if the columns is present and if not, it skips

Comment: Or another option is to rename after the map_dfr (assuming your excel datasets have the same column names).  The reason is that if a couple of sheets doesn't have the column, it will get filled with `NA` and thus your `set_names` could still work

Comment: All of them have the same column names. I don't have a vector neither, but where should I put it? I have edited the question since I forgot to include my 4 new columns in the code.

Comment: Just after the `map_dfr` i.e. `df <- map_df(file_list, load_files)` before you set the names, check the `names(df)` and its `ncol(df)` then, do `names(df) <- c("time", "power", ....)`

Comment: Please note that the modification in `mutate` before this step should be accounted for. i.e. you are using `time` to do some modification (after setting the colum name).  This should be changed to the original column name

Comment: the `names(df)` and `ncol(df)` codes resulted to `NULL`. The problem is that the error came just after the `map_df` code.

Comment: If the error came after the map_df, your `df` should have some columns

Comment: Also, there can be other places triggering the error `select(-(c(8:11, 14:15, 18:23, 29:32)))`  This assumes that the positions for the columns are fixed.  If some columns are missing, then removing columns based on index removes the wrong columns

Comment: the code has been updated for `select(-(c(8:11, 14:15, 18:23)))`. Indeed, the error message come only after the `map_df` code. Is that possible to provide a corrected code ? the `select` code is to remove the columns I don't want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show the names of `df` after this `df <- map_df(file_list, load_files)` i.e `names(df)`

Comment: I got this: `Error in `set_names()`:
! The size of `nm` (23) must be compatible with the size of `x` (25).
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> names(df)
NULL`

Comment: Please show the output of `dput(head(df, 3))` and update in your post

Comment: Here it is: ```structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
"    if (missing(ncp)) "), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3"), ""), class = "noquote")```

Comment: That looks like a function and not the output from `df <- map_df(file_list, load_files)`

Comment: Thank you Akrun for your support. From this code `df <- map_df(file_list, load_files)` I get this output: `Error in set_names():
! The size of nm (23) must be compatible with the size of x (25).
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.` ... and from this code: `dput(head(df, 3))` I get this output: `structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
"    if (missing(ncp)) "), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3"), ""), class = "noquote")`. Any idea ? Thank you!

Comment: That is why I mentioned you to use `set_names` later

Comment: You may have to read the data and check in the list, check before you do any transformations, i.e. `lst1 <- map(file_list, ~ read_excel(.x))`,  Then check the names/dim etc `map(lst1, names)`

Comment: Do you mean this code: `load_files <- function(files){
  temp <- read_excel(files) %>% 
    select(-(c(8:11, 14:15, 18:23))) %>%
    mutate(id = pull(.[4,1])) %>% ##ID
    mutate(body_mass = pull(.[7,3])) %>% ##body mass
    mutate(training = pull(.[4,2])) %>% ##training group
    slice(86:which(grepl("ration", VE))-1) %>% ##until recovery period
    mutate_at(vars(1:16), as.numeric) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(18), as.numeric) %>% 
    mutate(time = format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + time), "%H:%M", tz="UTC"),
           absVO2 = absVO2/1000, 
           VCO2 = VCO2/1000)
}` instead ?

Comment: Meaning that I have removed the `set_names` function from this.

Comment: You may have to debug with `lst1 <- map(file_list, ~ read_excel(.x))` and check whether some tibbles have less number of columns etc.  It is difficult for others to pinpoint the error without a reproducible example

Comment: I agree, I just don't know how I could produce a reproducible example if I can't even load my data correctly. Or maybe you have an idea ? I would be happy to send you the excel files. At the moment, I can't even go until the `map` function, since I get an error message by loading `load_files <- function(files){
  temp <- read_excel(files) %>% ...` code

Comment: I can share it via message (linkedin or other)?

Comment: You could post on github and share the link

Comment: I have tried this: we.tl/t-qJl3kVcY0j

Comment: Let me know if you are able to download the file. Thank you @akrun!

Comment: Sorry, it is an external website and I don't trust those.  I would prefer if it is github

Comment: Does this link work ? github.com/MaxBdn/Data.git

Comment: I checked that link.  It shows Data not found

Comment: It was private, sorry. Here it is : https://github.com/MaxBdn/Data